# How do I report Lasso results in an article?

Tags: interpretation, sas, lasso

I am using Lasso to reduce my number of variables and I have identified which variables had been retained after running my analysis (e.g. yrseduc, age). However, I don't know which numbers I should report in a scientific paper. I have been trying to find examples, but can't quite find the answer.

I am wondering if I just need to report the parameter estimates of all the variables that were found significant? Should I just report them in a table or in the text? If in the text, what do these numbers really mean?

[image: Example]

Thank you in advance, I am really at lost here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not a correct answer to this kind of question.

I have seen that some people use to write something like : "Lasso selects variables a,b,c and other 100 variables".  You can also report the table in an appendix. If you think it is very important you can leave the table in the text